# Docker set environment variable when restarting container

Tags: docker

I have a running container and i need to set an environment variable (in this case i want to . There is any way to restart and set the environment variable

I already tried something like that:

```
 docker restart CONTAINER_ID -e EXO_JVM_SIZE_MAX="7gb"

 docker -e EXO_JVM_SIZE_MAX="7gb" restart CONTAINER_ID
```

So is there any way to set a variable without losing the container?

I'm new at docker and i need some help

thanks in advance

Comment: You can go through at https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8838

Comment: ok, so i will do the following: docker stop CONTAINER_ID then i'll change the /var/lib/docker/containers/[container-id]/config.json (as they said) and add the EXO_JVM_SIZE_MAX="7gb" to the json and finally i will use the docker start CONTAINER_ID .. am i right? i'll not lose the container right?

Comment: I don't think you will lose container.If variable is required everytime then better you add it in image itself.

Comment: Hum.. didn't work, every time i start the docker the environment variable disappear